# CakePhp : new field in the database does not appear on find

Tags: database, caching, cakephp-2.0

I've added a new field in the database but when I retrieve the information regarding that model the new added field does not appear. I've deleted my cache (app/tmp/cache) but this doesn't seems to work.
Putting this line Configure::write('Cache.disable', true); in bootstrap.php make that field magically appear, but disabling the cache isn't something that I want to do, so I've deleted the line and the field is gone.

Does somebody have any idea what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean with 'not appear'? Are you using scaffolding? Did you 'bake' your views/models? Do you have some code to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: if you have mentioned field in find query and if you don't specify this newly added field there, you will not get this field in output array

Answer (score 2):

go to app/Config/core.php and change Configure::write('debug',2);
then run your code